# Problem of Returning the main class instead of the subclass JAVA android

Tags: java, android, class, subclass

I have a function and I would like it to return one of the subclasses which inherit from the same class.
The master class is button and the inheriting classes are button1, button2 ...
I do not understand when my function returns something it is always the characteristics of the master class that stand out.

My final goal is to pass the variable of a button class in function of a role user.
In the example bellow there are just the name.

Here it's how I declare the class `Button1`, `Button2` and the main class `button`.

```
...
    public static Button1 Button1;
    public static Button2 Button2;


    SettingsAdapter() {
        Button1 = new Button1();
        Button2 = new Button2();
    }

        public static class Button {
             final public static String name = "test";
        ...
        }

        /*** line 1 ***/

        public static class Button1 extends Button {
            final public static String name = "name 1";
            ...    
        }

        public static class Button2 extends Button {
            final public static String name = "name 2";
            ...
        }
```

Here it's the function

```
public static SettingsAdapter.Button getButtonPos(int a) {
        if (a == 1) {
            return Button1;
        } else {
            return Button2;
}
```

If we `printf(getButtonPos(1).name)`

The output is always `test`.

The output I want is `name 1`

How I can make this function really return the class of Button1 or Button2 ?

Comment: `if ()` ? What if? Does that compile?

Comment: And what did you expect the output to be?

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, but one thing that stands out to me is, that your button1 and button2 have two name fiels each (button.name and this.name). you might want to write to the name field of the button class instead of creating another field in the subclass.

Comment: I remove the the condition inside`If ()` for more clarity, but maybe I should not

Comment: The output I expect is `name 1`, I edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that the static key-word is the problem. Try to remove it.

A static variable is the same for all instances of this class, so every instance of a sublclass from button has a variable called name with value `"test"`.

Then button_1 has another variable called name with value `"name 1"`. I think java just takes the first one.

Also classe names are written in CamelCase, please refactor them. Static variables are in fact accessible with `ClassName.VariableName`

If it's not working without static, then use methods.
In Button make a method:

```java
public String getName(){
    return "test"
}
```

and just override this method in the subclasses:

```java
@Override
public String getName(){
    return "name 1"
}
```

At the print the value of getName().

```java
printf(getButtonPos(1).getName())
```

Another way is to retreive the class directly

```java
button1.getClass()
```

or

```java
button1.getClass().getName()
```

when a string is needed.

Comment: I tried to remove static but I have NullPointerException when I try to use an other variable of the class Button1 or Button2. This variable is create like this : `final public  int[] role = {};` . And cast like `Button1.role`

Comment: I'm trying the method where we need to override, thanks for your answer

Comment: Methods is the best anyway. Variables are used only in their own class most of the times. If you need access to them outside the class, use methods, so called Getters, to retreive their value.

Comment: Effectively call method is the best way. Thank you